# Need help to create a nested IF function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am planning a shrinkage planner. The need is to throw output based on a cell's value.

Requirement

I need the value of the cell based on the name of the employee and type of shrinkage. This is the formula I wrote.

```
=if(F10="January",VLOOKUP(F13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,4,0,(if(f10="February",VLOOKUP(F13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AD,6,0,(if(f10="March",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,8,0,(if(f10="April",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,10,0,(if(f10="May",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,12,0,(if(10="June",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,14,0,(f10="July",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,16,0,(iff10="August",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,18,0,(if(f10="September",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,20,0,(if(f10="October",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,22,0,(iff10="November",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,24,0,(VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,26,0)))))))))))
```

Throwing an error that I have entered too many arguments for this function.

Comment: Too many arguments means you are missing a `)` somewhere.

Comment: Looking through you formula, there are several errors. You should take the time to break it down line by line in Notepad and verify each statement has the correct brackets and number of arguments.

Comment: Michael Frank Thanks for your reply. Broke down the formulae, corrected the typo and included the correct no of ). Still the same error.

Comment: You should update your question with the corrected formula.

Comment: Also, your current formula has ~30 `(` and only 14 `)`. They need to balance or this will never work.

Comment: Use `CHOOSE(MonthNumber, ColumnNumForJan, ColumnNumForFeb, ...)` 
 in `VLOOKUP` argument instead of `IF`-s chain. Or absolutely simple `MonthNumber*2+2` in your particular case. To convert month name to its number you may yse a simple trick - add 1st num and any year, convert string date to date value (using DATEVALUE funcion), then extract month number from this date.

Comment: When you get a nesting that complicated, it's hard to troubleshoot or maintain.  It's time to look at an approach other than nesting IFs.  Start with a truth table of your conditions and results.  Post that and it will be easier for people to suggest a better approach.  It's unrealistic to expect people to go through your wall of formula to figure out what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a few problems.

For starters, your IF functions only have two arguments. For example, the outermost IF state has the following parameters:

```
F10="January",
VLOOKUP( ... )
```

To be correctly formatted, you should have a condition, a pass value, and a fail value.

Additionally, your VLOOKUP functions have 5 parameters. For example, the first VLOOKUP has the following parameters:

```
F13,
'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,
4,
0,
(IF( f10 = "February", .... ))
```

I think what you were intending is to have the VLOOKUP be the pass value and the next IF statement be the fail value. If that's correct, you should structure it like this:

```
=IF(F10="January",VLOOKUP(F13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,4,0), IF(F10="February", <next VLOOKUP>, <next IF>))
```

In particular, make sure you're closing out the VLOOKUPs instead of accidentally embedding the next IF inside of them.

On top of all that, there are various typos and missing functions in your expression. At one point you evaluate `10="June"` and another place you evaluate `iff10="August"`.

Comment: Fantastic. NightSicaruis. You are a savior. It worked!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just re-read this answer and I am glad for the OP that somehow it helped but I cannot understand how it would have helped.  It has so many falsehoods that it is confusing.  As an example, the first VLOOKUP **does not** have 5 parameters, and although you are stating that IF statements must have a fail parameter, it does (The next IF onwards). It's just that this part has structure issues (see my answer)

Comment: The first VLOOKUP as the OP wrote does have 5 parameters. The first nested IF is one of the VLOOKUP parameters. The main problem they complained about was "too many arguments", which is primarily caused by their incorrect use of commas and brackets. For the first nested IF to be the fail parameter, they'd first need to close the VLOOKUP the comprises the "pass" condition of the outer IF.

Comment: AND that's pretty much what you said in your answer (missing closing brackets on the VLOOKUP), so I'm not sure why you're arguing against my response.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments you need to break the formula up in notepad or similar and your formula is easily broken up by typing it in the following manner...

```
=if(F10="January",VLOOKUP(F13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,4,0,

(if(f10="February",VLOOKUP(F13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AD,6,0,

(if(f10="March",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,8,0,

(if(f10="April",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,10,0,

(if(f10="May",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,12,0,

(if(10="June",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,14,0,

(f10="July",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,16,0,

(iff10="August",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,18,0,

(if(f10="September",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,20,0,

(if(f10="October",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,22,0,

(iff10="November",VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,24,0,

(VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,26,0)))))))))))
```

For debugging purposes, take out all **close brackets** at the end leaving

```
(VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,26,0
```

This way it matches your previous sections.

The first section provides your conditions if cell `F10` is equal to `"January"`.  The second section onwards is if it is not.

The 2nd section then provides your conditions if cell `F10` is equal to `"February"`.  The third section onwards is if it is not.... and so on.

Let's look at your first section.  This looks good, except your `VLOOKUP` is not closed.  You need a close bracket at the end to close it.  Add that before the comma at the end to make

```
=if(F10="January",VLOOKUP(F13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,4,0),
```

You have the same problem in the other sections.  Do the same for every section except with the last section where you need a close bracket at the very end.

For the second section onwards take out all the open brackets at the beginning.  **You don't need them** and they add to the confusion.

The rest is straight forward when going through the rest of the sections from section 2 onwards.

Section 6 (June) you have no `F` in the cell reference for cell `F10`

Section 7 (July) you have no `IF` at the beginning

Section 8 (August) you haven't opened the `IF()` function so you need an open bracket after `IF`.  The same goes for section 11 (November).

Now your sections look good you need to close all the `IF()` functions as they are all still open (you have no close brackets at the ends).

Count your `IF` statements and add that many close brackets to the end of the last section.  You have 11 `IF` statements in this case so with the close bracket already there you need to have 12 close brackets at the end leaving

```
VLOOKUP(f13,'[Team Spartans Attendance Planner - Data Extaction File.xlsm]Rep Wise Shrinkage Mthly'!$C:$AC,26,0))))))))))))
```

You are now left with rejoining the sections together to form one nested `IF()` formula which should work.